# Set "No Common Blocks" to NO for CocoaPods

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I have project ios using flutter. And the build system are from terminal for flutter, flutter build system always failed because I have to set the Pods project for property "No Common Blocks" to NO.
I can do it by open the xworkspace with XCode and edit there.

My question: is it possible to set this property on Podfile?

So I don't need to open XCode to build. Usually I use only XCode if I want to make release build and upload to App Store. For debug I always use flutter build system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projects created with `flutter create` all include debug and release `.xcconfig` files, where you can override any Xcode setting.

To update the 'No common blocks' setting for your Flutter project, edit `ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig` and/or `ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig` and add the following line:

```
GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = NO
```

If you need to set it for the Pods project created by CocoaPods, CocoaPods includes the ability to register post-`pod install` actions. You can add the following to your `Podfile` to set the build setting in question:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```